# Error - Unable to update Facebook Payments settings

Tags: facebook-credits

I want to add credits to my fb app but I am unable to add a callback url. I get a "Unable to update Facebook Payments settings." error every time. Has anyone found the cause or a solution for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: This may be a bug, what is your appID and the desired callback URL so I can take a further look

Comment: App ID - 126610450760374 and callback url - http://<mydomain>/callback.php and in the php I just have one echo statement.

Comment: is there other way to add the credits callback url? it might be something with the form submission. This is holding up my business and I did not expect that issues like this one would come up in facebook.

Comment: Hello. I have the same error and I can't get around it. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: delete the app and create a new one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the app and created a new one. That solved the issue.

Comment: 'I created a new app' isn't really an answer to why that error message was appearing

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Company Country at the same time as the callback URL. Theoretically, once you've done that once, you can then update just the callback URL as you like in the future.